# Are there trading fees when trading on DEXes like eosfinex?

Tags: decentralized-exchange

Are there trading fees on DEXes like eosfinex? How do they make money if it is truly decentralized? What about other DEXes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Trading-fees on dexes have nothing to do with eosio-development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They said that there is "minimal fees" on https://www.eosfinex.com/
I think you also have other DEXes like:

https://newdex.io/

https://www.bancor.network/